# О чередовании согласных К/Т в словах "паук ― паутина"

Tags: этимология, морфология, фонетика, чередования

Из словаря: **паук ― паутина**.

Чередование К/Т является историческим? Как оно объясняется и в каких еще словах встречается?

Comment: Может, -К – это суффикс?

Comment: Паук - непроизводное слово, сравнить: onkos (др.-греч.) - крючок, др.-инд.acati- сгибать, поэтому УК - исторический корень, паук назван по свои изогнутым лапам.

Comment: @Jasmin если УК исторический корень, то ПА - отрицание качества  (ср. пасынок, падчерица). Получается, что паук - "несгибаемый". Неувязочка.

Comment: Это у Черных "неувязочка", я его только озвучиваю. Он считает, что pa - префикс. Только удивляется, что ударение не на первом слоге, сравнивая: пажить, пагуба. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/па-  О значении приставки ПА (1) сходство, 2) неполнота, 3)отсутствие), неполнота: образует существительные со значением неполноты, несовершенства ◆ патрубок, пасынок, падчерица, паводок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу цитату из Этимологического словаря современного русского языка А. К. Шапошникова:

> Из рус. диал. *паутина* (из **паукина*) (**результат смешения двух чередовательных рядов согласных: к/ч и т/ч**), согласно другой трактовке, собств.-рус. преобразование под влиянием *путина* «путы» (от глаг. *путать*), унаследованного из праслав. слова **паõчина*, производного с суф. *-ина* от **паõкъ*.

Таким образом, чередования к//т нет вовсе (либо можно сказать, что оно есть, но встречается лишь в морфеме /паук/), *паут-* — алломорф, т. е. вариант корня *паук*. Если вдруг найдутся другие слова с чередованием к//т, то почти со стопроцентной вероятностью оно опять будет свойственно какой-либо одной морфеме, это не систематическое явление.

Добавление: к примерам, приведенным в другом ответе, есть вопросы, а именно:
1) какую именно систему образуют варианты пуск-/пуст- и паук-/паут-? Сказано: «Все такие корни оканчиваются на -к, которое переходит в т вместо ожидаемого ч в позиции палатализации (но не перед деминутивным -к)». Проверим: паук — паутина, все работает; пустить — пускать, не работает, т. к. -ст- исходно, а -ск- — производное, возможно, от *пущать*. Исторически это **два совершенно разных случая**. Но мы имеем дело с синхронией, о чем см. п. 2.

2) морфологическое чередование является результатом действовавших в прошлом фонетических законов; так, морфологическое чередование к//ч в современном языке исторически обусловлено действием закона слогового сингармонизма и закона открытого слога (ср. пеку — печь) в прошлом. Предлагаемое чередование к//т, которое объединяет слова с совершенно разной историей развития, **не имеет под собой общей для всех примеров исторической морфонологической системы**, а потому едва ли может быть признано и в синхронии. Иными словами, морфологические чередования проходят стадию фонетических, чего в к//т не наблюдается.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я заглянула еще в словарь Черных, он тоже считает, что это нефонетическое чередование. Также у него приводится интересная информация о том, что сначала существовало слово паучина/паючина (с 11 в.), а паутина зафиксирована в словаре только с 1762 года. Также есть слово паут - областное название овода, а в некоторых говорах так называют паука. Чередование К/Т появилось, вероятно,  под влиянием глагола "путать"

Answer (score 3):

> Из словаря: **паук ― паутина**.
>
> Чередование К/Т является историческим? Как оно объясняется и в каких
>   еще словах встречается?

Одна из версий (из "Лекций по истории русского языка" А.И. Соболевского):

> …Заметим следующее. Слово *паутина* (великор. и малор.-галицк.),
>   которое обыкновенно считают происшедшим из *пау**к**ина* и рядом с
>   которым существует слово *пау**ч**ина*, происходит не от *паук*, а от
>   другого слова с тем же значением – *пау**т***, существующего теперь и
>   с значением *паук* (в Ярославской губ.)…

По поводу чередования *к ~ т*…

Из книги Иткина И.Б. "Русская морфонология" (М., 2007):

> Чередование *к ~ т*, никогда ранее не выделявшееся в качестве особого
>   МФН-явления РЯ, охватывает около десятка корней – *пуск- ~ пуст-,
>   черк- ~ черт-, паук- ~ паут-* и др.  Распределение морфов с исходом на
>   *-к* и на *-т* на первый взгляд кажется хаотичным, но на поверку большинство примеров удается описать следующим правилом: все такие
>   корни оканчиваются на *-к*, которое переходит в *т* вместо ожидаемого
>   *ч* в позиции палатализации (но не перед деминутивным *-к*), ср. *блеск, отблеск, проблескивать, блескучий*, но  *блестеть, блестящий, блестка; искать, выискивать, поиск, розыск, иск, исковой*, но *истец*;
>   *ласка* "нежность", *ласковый, ласкать*, но *ластиться*; *смекать, смекалка, намекать, намекнуть, намек* (при разг. *намечек*),
>   *невдомек*, но *сметка, сметливый; мелькать, мелькнуть, мельком, промельк*, но *мельтешить; паук* (при *паучок*), но *паутина*…
>
> …Следует признать, что корни этого типа имеют в ауслауте особую
>   морфонему – {к/т} .

То же {к/т} обнаруживается ВНУТРИ корня в одной уникальной морфеме,

> ср. *шпаклевать, шпаклевка*, но *шпатель*…

Comment: Вопрос к цитируемой вами работе И. Б. Иткина: для пуск-/пуст- исходным морфом является пуст-. Как, спрашивается, это согласуется с описанным правилом (которое, кажется, не вполне конкретно и теоретически несовершенно)? Также насчет шпателя: берется ли в расчет наличие параллельных форм шпа**т**левка и шпа**к**левка и мотивационная связь _шпатель — шпатлевать_, т. е., вероятно, и для шпак-/шпат- исходен вариант на т?

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что данное явление не поддается точной классификации, нет какого-то одного убедительного объяснения не потому, что мы его пока не нашли, а потому, что его просто не  существует. Можете назвать это случайной флуктуацией.

В части конкретного вопроса паук-паут я допускаю подход Иткина (см. slava1947), вывод  Т<Ч<К вполне в духе явления палатализации, но есть очень большое "но".

Хотел было комментарием ограничиться, но переросла мысль комментарий.

> охватывает около десятка корней – пуск- ~ пуст-, черк- ~ черт-, паук-
>   ~ паут- и др.

Вот вечно Иткин все в одну кучу смешает... Все бы у него хорошо, только "пуск(ать)" - это древнее суффиксальное образование от "пустити", какие встречаются в русском - ласкать-ластить(ся), блистать-блеск (с известной ступенью вокализма е-и) и проч.

Тут вообще чередования **ск/ст** надо рассматривать, если уж придерживаться той версии, что это один корень, то есть забыть о произошедшем историческом морфемном переразложении.

А "паук-паут" тогда становится уникальным, как и еще один-два  оставшихся примера, которые уже ни под какое единое "МФН-явление" (вернее сказать МФН-правило) не подпадают.

Что касается Соболевского, то такая версия известна мне ещё со школы, но стопроцентно убедительной я бы её не назвал. Морфологического ряда не вижу. У паука-паутины он есть, а вот у гипотетического диалектного слова не просматривается. Да и само по себе оно странновато как первичный морф из-за зияния гласных. Скорее можно предположить вторичное "паут" от "паутина", чем наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

1. Чередование К/Т для слов паук ― паутина историческим не является.

Острожская библия:

1. събысть же ся домъ его яко молие, и якоже **паучина** яже снабде
2. **паучина** же събудется храмъ его
3. Лета нашя яко **паучина** **паучахуся**, дние летъ нашихъ в нихъ же седъмьдесятъ летъ.
4. и истаялъ еси яко **паучину** душу его
5. яица аспидъска разбиша, и поставъ **паучь** ткутъ

Могу предположить, что этимологически паучина - это форма полного притяжательного прилагательного от существительного паук, отвечающая на вопрос чья.