# Иск, истина, чин — однокоренные слова?

Tags: этимология

Нашёл на просторах интернета:

Истина происходит от краткого прилагательного женского рода "иста" путем добавления суффикса "ин" (см. пример "А" ниже), которое, в свою очередь, происходит от слова иск ("к" меняется на "т" по правилу чередования согласных старославянской речи, см. пример "В")

Пример "А":

ст.-слав. среда -> рус. середина;

ст.-слав. говяда -> рус. говядина;

ст.-слав. велика -> рус. величина

ст.-слав. стара -> рус. старина

ст.-слав. слаба -> рус. слабина

ст.-слав. тиха -> рус. тишина

ст.-слав. всяка -> рус. всячина

Пример "В"

ст.-слав. иудеистии -> рус. иудеские;

ст.-слав. израильстии -> рус. израильские

Архаизмами данного правила в русской речи являются:

пуск -> пустить;

черкать -> чертить;

паук -> паутина;

щека -> щетина;

ласкаться -> ластиться;

блеск -> блистать;

рыск -> ристать.

Comment: Даже если Вы нашли "на просторах интернета" так много примеров словообразования, не обязательно было все их приводить в качестве пояснения к своему вопросу. Там есть ошибки, и вряд ли кто-то возьмётся проверять всё, в чём "неправ кто-то из интернета".

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443838/%D0%9E-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%9A-%D0%A2-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 4):

Сущ. *истина* образовано от прил. *истый* 'такой, какой должен быть'.

*Иск* — производное от *искать*.

*Чин* — древнее слово индоевропейской природы, содержащее тот же корень, что и, например, в глаг. *чинить*.

Между этими тремя словами нет никакой этимологической связи. Все они разнокоренные.

<sup>См., напр., словарь А. К. Шапошникова.</sup>