# Москва и Моства

Tags: этимология

Можно ли отнести слова Москва и Моства к этимологически однокоренным, по аналогии с [блес**к** -> блис**т**ать](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448065/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0) ?

Answer (score 1):

Согласно Фассмеру, название реки "Мста" происходит от финского слова  "mustа" ("черная"). Можно предположить, что "Моства" того же происхождения.

Происхождение же слова "Москва" до сих пор является предметом споров и гипотез:

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0_%C2%AB%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%C2%BB

https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-7936.htm

К некоторым из этих гипотез стоит отнестись с осторожностью, так как они предполагают, что обсуждаемое слово кончается на -ва. Между тем из Ипатьевской летописи известно, что по-древнерусски город назывался "Московь".